# suggest me a example for non singular, conjugate-symmetric sesquilinear form ????

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

I only know that fact that the matrix corresponding to the non singular, conjugate-symmetric sesquilinear form is a unitary matrix.

and SU_n(q) is the unitary groups  is the collection of the isometry forms, Can you suggest typical example along with how the matrix will look like.

Answer (score 0):

$SU(2)$ consists of all two-by-two matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}a&-\bar{b}\\b&\bar{a}\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a, b\in \mathbb{C}$ and $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$. You can think of it as the unit sphere $S^3$ sitting in $\mathbb{R}^4$.